# How do I fill a Combobox with days in month using an DateTime.DaysInMonth

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I am trying to fill a ComboBox with the days in the selected month with this

```
    private void cboSelectMonth_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if (cboSelectMonth.SelectedIndex >= 0)
       {
            int year = Convert.ToInt32(cboSelectYear.SelectedValue);
            int month = Convert.ToInt32(cboSelectMonth.SelectedValue);

            this.cboSelectDay.DisplayMember = "Text";
            this.cboSelectDay.ValueMember = "Value";

            int dayCount = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month);
            var days = new[ dayCount+1 ] { };

            for (int i = 1; i < dayCount +1; i++)
            {
                days[i] = new { Text = Convert.ToString(i), Value = i };
                //cboSelectDay.Items.Add(i);
                //   days[]  { new { Text = Convert.ToString(i), Value = i } };
            }

            this.cboSelectDay.DataSource = days;

            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            int dayValue = now.Day;

            cboSelectDay.SelectedIndex = dayValue - 1; 
       }
    }
```

So I am trying to end up with a ComboBox that lists all days from the current month. For instance, choosing September is going to add 30 days tot the ComboBox and choosing October would give you 31 etc. I am getting two errors. The first is on the `var days = new[ dayCount+1 ] { };` line, which says that a `']'` is exptected. The second error is on the `days[i] = new { Text = Convert.ToString(i), Value = i };`line which says Cannot implicitly convert type `'AnonymousType#1' to 'int'`

I am trying to do something similar to what I am doing with the Months, which does work (code block below). What am I doing wrong?

```
    private void FillMonthCombobox()
    {
        this.cboSelectMonth.DisplayMember = "Text";
        this.cboSelectMonth.ValueMember = "Value";

        var months = new[] 
        { 
            new { Text = "January", Value = 1 }, 
            new { Text = "February", Value = 2 }, 
            new { Text = "March", Value = 3 }, 
            new { Text = "April", Value = 4 }, 
            new { Text = "May", Value = 5 }, 
            new { Text = "June", Value = 6 }, 
            new { Text = "July", Value = 7 }, 
            new { Text = "Aughust", Value = 8 }, 
            new { Text = "September", Value = 9 }, 
            new { Text = "October", Value = 10 }, 
            new { Text = "November", Value = 11 }, 
            new { Text = "December", Value = 12 } 
        };
        this.cboSelectMonth.DataSource = months;

        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        int monthValue = now.Month;
        cboSelectMonth.SelectedIndex = monthValue - 1;
    }
```

**Edit:** I can populate the ComboBox now but how do I add the Text = day and the Value = day to the loop so I can reference the Value later? In the case of this loop they will be the same but in the case of some other loops I am working with they will be different. Essentially I want to do the same thing I am doing in the second code block but with a loop.

Comment: It is just not valid code, anonymous types were not made for this.  You are going to have to write a tiny private helper class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple, but you have to specify a year, too. Mind February and leap years!

```
int year = 2015;
int month = 5;
int[] days = Enumerable.Range(1, DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month)).ToArray();
```

You can specify it as a `DataSource` afterwards:

```
cboSelectDay.DataSource = days;
cboSelectDay.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1):

Using your general approach, this does work:

```
int thisMonthsDays = DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month);

for (int i = 1; i <= thisMonthsDays; i++) { comboBox1.Items.Add(i);  }
```

It fills a comboBox1 with (for May) with 31 days as expected.

Trying to work through and grasp it better, I think this update will help:

First a small class:

```
public class YearClass
    {
        public int IndexOfMonth { get; set; }
        public string DayName { get; set; }
    }
```

And now additional code to bind the month's days to a comboBox:

```
 List<YearClass> months = new List<YearClass>();
            int thisMonthsDays = DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month);

            for (int i = 1; i <= thisMonthsDays; i++)
            {
                YearClass currentDay = new YearClass();
                    currentDay.IndexOfMonth = i;
                    DateTime dt = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, i);
                    currentDay.DayName = dt.DayOfWeek.ToString();
                    months.Add(currentDay);
            }

            comboBox1.DataSource = months;
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "DayName";
```

The output then looks like:

[image]

Comment: It does work but how do I add the Text = day and the Value = day.to the loop so I can reference the Value later? In the case of this loop they will be the same but in the case of some other loops I am working with they will be different.

Comment: @BukHix see my answer. It's as simple as setting `DataSource = `. You don't need Text & Value then, because both are the same.

Comment: @bytecode77 I can't believe it was that simple. Austin French your sample helped me for the very next task. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can do this - I am passing hard coded values for year and month

```
for (int i = 0; i < DateTime.DaysInMonth(2015, 05); i++)
{ 
cmbMonth.Items.Add(i.ToString());
}
```

let me know if you have any other requirement